# What should be the data type of field 'email' in Postgresql database in pgadmin 4?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

You can see that I am getting 'No results found' when searching for varchar.

[image]I need to know the data type that I should select for 'email' in postgresql database.

Comment: you shouldn't limit yourself to GUI tools. Learn how to create a table using SQL, then you can use all documented data types (including aliases which the UI won't let you select)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the past I used **text** or **varchar** or **character varying**

Comment: varchar is not in the option but there is character varying. Should I go with character varying?

Comment: @SaketSuraj: `varchar` **is** a valid data type in Postgres (it's an alias for `character varying`) https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=d8c0bf80f3e989d92fbf69da7cc553bc

Comment: Yeah, varchar is an alias for character varying. Of couse you can use `character varying`. Initially I used it, but later I prefer `varchar` especially if you need to restrict length (for this use varchar(N) or simple `text`

Comment: You can restrict the length for character varying as well `character varying(150)` is valid

Answer (score 4):

Apart from using of VARCHAR (as suggested by @Maria), you might get some insight from this link:
https://www.dbrnd.com/2018/04/postgresql-how-to-validate-the-email-address-column/
and from this https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/68266/what-is-the-best-way-to-store-an-email-address-in-postgresql

if you read some parts of it, they created their own functions or constraints, which would likely help you in understanding PSQL more.

TL/DR, or the links might change in the future (shamelessly taken from one of the links):

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION citext;
CREATE DOMAIN domain_email AS citext
CHECK(
   VALUE ~ '^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$'
);
-- for valid samples
SELECT 'some_email@gmail.com'::domain_email;
SELECT 'accountant@dbrnd.org'::domain_email;
-- for an invalid sample
SELECT 'dba@aol.info'::domain_email;
```

As [Neil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6269559/neil-guy-lindberg) had pointed out, yeah it's just like using custom TYPES.

> `CREATE DOMAIN` creates a new domain. A domain is essentially a data type with optional constraints (restrictions on the allowed set of values).
> [source](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-createdomain.html)

For those of you unfamiliar with the weird characters used to check the value, it's a [regex pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

And an example used with a table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE sample_table ( id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, email domain_email );

-- The following is invalid, because ".info" has 4 characters
-- the regex pattern only allows 2-3 characters
INSERT INTO sample_table (email) VALUES ('sample_email@gmail.info');
ERROR:  value for domain domain_email violates check constraint "domain_email_check"

-- The following query is valid
INSERT INTO sample_table (email) VALUES ('sample_email@gmail.com');
SELECT * FROM sample_table;
 id |         email
----+------------------------
  1 | sample_email@gmail.com
(1 row)
```

Thanks [Neil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6269559/neil-guy-lindberg) for the suggestion.

Comment: I really like your answer, but I think throwing in a CREATE TABLE that uses the DOMAIN you've created here to define the column datatype would be more complete.

Comment: I’m sorry, you mean I edit my comment and add a CREATE TABLE example with my suggested solution embedded/integrated? If that’s what you mean, then sure I’ll edit this =) Otherwise, can you please rephrase what you said? Sorry, english, like most of us perhaps, isn’t my first language.

Comment: Yeah, I was suggesting an edit. I just totally found this useful, but wasn't immediately sure how to use the domain in table creation. Ends up it is just like using custom TYPES. At the time of my response I had created my first DOMAIN.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you yo use [`CITEXT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/citext.html) type that ignores case in values comparison. It's important for email to prevent duplication like **username@example.com** and **UserName@example.com**.

This type is the part of the `citext` extension that could be activates by the following query:

```
CREATE EXTENSION citext;
```